# Angular Datepicker off by one day

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue with the angular ui datepicker.  I have this value stored in the database: 2014-12-21T05:00:00.000Z and if I just have a plain text box bound to I get the output below.  But when I add the data-picker directive it decrements a day off the value and displays 12-20-2014 instead of the correct 12-21-2014.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

```
<input type="text" ng-model="incident.createdDate"  /><p />
output is: 2014-12-21T05:00:00.000Z

<input type="text" ng-model="incident.createdDate" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" /><p />
output is: 12-20-2014
```

Comment: The date in the database is UTC. What's the time on the "incorrect" date? Is there a timezone offset?

Comment: Thank you, the time part could just be ignored, we are only interested in selecting, storing and displaying the date part with datepicker.  How do I ignore or fix the time part so that it displays correctly?

Comment: this is the control I'm using: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: When you get the date string from the database, convert it to a  [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) before assigning it to your model because the datepicker will localize the value.